# Find start and end date of selected period in p:schedule

Tags: jsf, primefaces, schedule

**Requirement:** I want to load some data from my Database based on week start date and end date. In Default, I am able to load the current week Data because from the current date I am able to get the week start date and end date.
**Problem:** When user click Next and Previous button of Schedule component how to get the start and end date of that week.

Comment: Tried using Ajax?

Comment: @Kukeltje Is there any sample so that I can refer it?

Comment: PrimeFaces showcase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just check the [showcase for `p:schedule`](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/schedule.xhtml). When a different period is selected, the `ScheduleEvent#loadEvents(Date start, Date end)` method will be called.

From the showcase, in `ScheduleView.java`:

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    eventModel = new DefaultScheduleModel();
    // Some default events are added here

    lazyEventModel = new LazyScheduleModel() {

        @Override
        public void loadEvents(Date start, Date end) {
            Date random = getRandomDate(start);
            addEvent(new DefaultScheduleEvent("Lazy Event 1", random, random));

            random = getRandomDate(start);
            addEvent(new DefaultScheduleEvent("Lazy Event 2", random, random));
        }   
    };
}
```